# Read and Write Text in ANSI format

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, ansi, bufferedwriter

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.io.*;

public class CSVConverter 
{
    private File csvFile;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private StringBuffer strBuffer;
    private BufferedWriter writer;
    int startNumber = 0;
    private String strString[];

    public CSVConverter(String location, int startNumber)
    {
        csvFile = new File(location);
        strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        this.startNumber = startNumber;


        //Read
        try
        {
         reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
         String line = "";

         while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
         {
             String[] array = line.split(",");

             String inputQuery = "insertQuery["+startNumber+"] = \"insert into WordList_Table ('Engl','Port','EnglishH','PortugueseH','Numbe','NumberOf','NumberOfTime','NumberOfTimesPor')values('"+array[0]+"','"+array[2]+"','"+array[1]+"','"+array[3]+"',0,0,0,0)\"";

             strBuffer.append(inputQuery+";"+"\r\n");
             startNumber++;

         }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       System.out.println(strBuffer.toString());

        //Write
        try
        {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/list.txt");
            FileWriter filewrite = new FileWriter(file);

            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }


            writer = new BufferedWriter(filewrite);


            writer.write(strBuffer.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new CSVConverter("C:/Users/list.csv",90);
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a CSV file, edit the text in code, and write it back to a `.txt` file. My issue is, I have Portuguese words, so the file should be read and write using `ANSI` format. Right now some Portuguese words are replaced with symbols in the output file.

How can I read and write text data into a file in ANSI format in Java?

Comment: List<String> farmacias = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:\\tmp\\Farmacias.txt"), Charset.forName("Cp1252"));

Comment: I don't agree about > The right Java encoding for Windows ANSI is Cp1252 ANSI is Microsoft's trick, and can be set into varies encoding. It could also be GBK, Shift_JIS and so on, depending on the setting of Windows.

Answer (score 85):

To read a text file with a specific encoding you can use a `FileInputStream` in conjunction with a `InputStreamReader`. The right Java encoding for Windows ANSI is `Cp1252`.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), "Cp1252"));
```

To write a text file with a specific character encoding you can use a `FileOutputStream` together with a `OutputStreamWriter`.

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "Cp1252"));
```

The classes `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` translate between byte oriented streams and text with a specific character encoding.

Comment: Why isn't Cp1252 listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)?

Comment: Maybe this list is more informative: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html