# java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Tags: java, io, character-encoding, malformed

I have this (stripped the HTML tags for the code example) function that builds a HTML table out of a CSV, but I get a runtime error everytime I try to run it and I don't know why. Google says that maybe something with the encoding is wrong but I have no idea how to change that.

My CSV is encoded in ANSI and contains characters like ä, Ä, Ü, Ö but I have no control over the encoding or if it will change in the future.

The error occurs here:

```
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
at testgui.Csv2Html.start(Csv2Html.java:121)
```

Line 121 is

```
lines.forEach(line -> {
```

Sourcecode:

```
protected void start() throws Exception {

    Path path = Paths.get(inputFile);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);      

    boolean withTableHeader = (inputFile.length() != 0);
    try  {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            try {
                String[] columns = line.split(";");
                for (int i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
                    columns[i] = escapeHTMLChars(columns[i]);
                }       
                if (withTableHeader == true && firstLine == true) {
                    tableHeader(ps, columns);
                    firstLine = false;
                } else {
                    tableRow(ps, columns);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
        });

    } finally {
        ps.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: For current (and future) reference: It is immensely helpful if you also tell us on which line of code the Exception is occurring.

Comment: *I get a runtime error everytime I try to run it*  Which error ? Please share.

Comment: Sorry, added the relevant part of the exception and the line number.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try to utilize the correct encoding by using the `Files.lines(Path path, Charset charset)` form of the `lines` method ([javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)).

[Here's a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) of supported encodings (for the Oracle JVM anyhow).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559395/2494555) indicates that "Cp1252" is Windows ANSI.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it :) - Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile), Charset.forName("Cp1252")); Do you also know where I have to close my Stream? Eclipse warns me about a ressource leak because I don't call lines.close() but I don't know where to put it, tried the finally {} blocks but that gives me an exception because it seems I closed the Stream too early.

Comment: You can use the try-with-resources to close the stream automatically after it's finished being used:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile), Charset.forName("Cp1252")) { ... your parsing code here ... }

Comment: thanks for the response, on how to fix I had this problem too when reading file using streams, when I read file using BufferedReader(FileReader) implementation error did not show so it was driving me mad, thanks for showing Stream api's handle different encoding for reading csv files.