# Why error? (java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1)

Tags: java

Java code:

```
 String fileName = "settings.txt";

 String text = "AdresProgramm =";
 String delimiter = ";";

 Optional<String> result =
 Files
     .lines(Paths.get(fileName))
     .filter(e -> e.contains(text))
     .map(e -> {
         int start = e.indexOf(text);
         int end = e.indexOf(delimiter, start + text.length());

             return e.substring(start, end);
     })
     .findFirst();

 result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

File contents: `AdresProgramm =D:\\ЭСЧФ\;`

> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Comment: It seems that it's an encoding problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609062/java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input-length-1

Answer (score 1):

As you could see from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), the `lines` method you used requires that the input file is in UTF-8 encoding. It seems that it *wasn't* the case for you. You can override the default encoding with the other overload of the `lines` methods like this:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("windows-1251"))
```

Comment: I think this answer needs an explanation as to "why" that charset wouldwork

Comment: Explain that the overloaded `lines(Path)` uses UTF-8, which fails on Cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding issue because of the cyrillic alphabet you are using.

Think the ISO-8859-1 encoding works for European characters apparently. Not sure if UTF-8 will work.

Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268132/all-inclusive-charset-to-avoid-java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input) page?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but may be useful to others facing this issue while coding to read mainframe files.

Use this like below:

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

IBM calls it code page 819 or CP819. This is a life saver if you are processing Extended Binary format files sourced from Mainframe systems.