# Java FileUtils.writeLines in ANSI format with New line as CR LF

Tags: java, linux

I would like to write file in JAVA

- Encoding : ANSI
- New line: CR LF

Example:

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File(baseFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + filename), data);
```

I am using `Apache FileUtils.writeLines` but it is always in `UTF-8` not `ANSI` and new line as `LF` and not `CR LF`?

Server is `Linux` not `Windows`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708991/setting-java-vm-line-separator and read beyond the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke the appropriate overload of [`writeLines`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String)), with the parameters in the right order:

> ```
> public static void writeLines(File file,
>           String encoding,
>           Collection<?> lines,
>           String lineEnding)
>                    throws IOException
> ```

e.g.

```
FileUtils.writeLines(
    new File(baseFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename),
    "Cp1252",
    data,
    "\r\n");
```

Note that Windows ANSI isn actually called `Cp1252` in Java, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559395/3788176).

---

You are passing the encoding as the last parameter to [this overload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines(java.io.File,%20java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String)), which is actually the line ending parameter.

> ```
> public static void writeLines(File file,
>           Collection<?> lines,
>           String lineEnding)
>                    throws IOException
> ```