# What is the proper encoding to use with item Reader

Tags: java, encoding, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to read csv files, when I open these files with Notepad++ I see that the used encode is `encode in ANSI`.
Now when reading a line from a file, I notice that all accent character are not shown correctly. For example let's take this line:

```
Données issues de la reprise des données
```

It's transformed to be like this one with some special characters:

[image]

So as first solution I set the encode for my Item Reader to `utf-8` but the problem still exist.

- I thought that with `UTF-8` encoding all my accent characters will be recognized, is that not true ?  from what I heard UTF-8 is the best encoding to use to handle all character on web page for example ?

After setting my item Reader encoding to `ISO-8859-1`:

```
public class TestItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<TestFileRow> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestItemReader.class);
    public ScelleItemReader(String path) {

        this.setResource( new FileSystemResource(path + "/Test.csv"));
        this.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

I cant see that these character are now displayed correctly.

- As output I should write with `utf-8` as encoding, did this is correct if I use `ISO-8859-1` as encoding input and `utf-8` as output?

Comment: "My question is that why when i try to set the itemReader encoding to utf-8 still persist ?" - Um, because the file isn't in UTF-8. Its not clear what you're asking, to be honest.

Comment: i update the post

Comment: I suspect you don't understand how encodings work. If a file is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and you try to read it using UTF-8, it's a bit like trying to use a PNG reader to load a JPEG image. UTF-8 can represent every character in Unicode, but that doesn't mean you can arbitrarily use it for files that are encoded in a different encoding.

Comment: You might want to read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx - it's phrased in terms of C#, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Ok, so there no the concept of a global encode that is capable to read any format. i should use the same encoding as mentioned on notepadd ++

Comment: Well "ANSI" isn't a single encoding either. If you can change what's producing the CSV files to output UTF-8, that would be the best thing. But if you can't change that, you should find out what encoding it's using (without just relying on Notepad++).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help and clarifications

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Input file is ANSI, and "ü" gets displayed as a square in the output.

That's because your input file is encoded in ANSI, but by default, [Spring Batch assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) (6.6.2 FlatFileItemReader).
*Update 2023:* in newer versions, the default is UTF-8, but back when the question was posted, it was ISO-8859-1 instead, as verifiable by checking older versions of the linked document; for instance, [version 4.0.1.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#readersAndWriters). I'm not sure which version was current back then, but the point remains the same either way.

Therefore, you have to set the encoding for your reader to "Cp1252" (`setEncoding("Cp1252")`) - [that's how Java refers to ANSI encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556104/read-and-write-text-in-ansi-format)

Furthermore, you will have to set your writer's encoding to "utf-8". I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't work with other encodings (that are generally able to display "ü", such as ISO-8859-1), but it works with UTF-8, so that's what I'm using.

Comment: Default encoding in FlatFileItemReader is UTF-8 as per document you have shared. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right @ankush__ , the default encoding set in AbstractFileItemWriter is utf-8

Comment: @ankush__ I have not worked with Spring Batch for years, but I think the default has simply changed since 2018 when I originally wrote the answer. Checking older versions of the linked document confirms this. For example, Spring Batch version 4.0.1 RELEASE shows default encoding ISO-8859-1: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#readersAndWriters

Comment: Thanks. You are right that default encoding has changed.

Answer (score 0):

i use the same encoding "ISO-8859-1", all character are displayed correctly.