# How to write the input String with french accents as it is to the output file in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I get a input file to spring batch with inputs having french accent like this-
ÉTAGE, ÉDIFICE.
However in Spring batch while writing into a different file it is written as like this-
�TAGE, �DIFICE

How to resolve this. I want the same data in output file as well.

Comment: I think you need to see Character Encoding in your code execution. If you would use UTF8, I think you won't face this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303899/what-is-the-proper-encoding-to-use-with-item-reader

Comment: Thanks @GauravJeswani,  setting itemWriter.setEncoding("utf-8") resolved the issue.

Comment: @sathyap Perfect, good to know it helped.

Comment: Default encoding for windows in Java causes the issue, while in linux it's UTF8 by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi , Sorry for the delayed update. the default encoding is "UTF-8".
 I used "ISO-8859-1"
reader.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); to resolve the issue.
Thanks